# Can we control the k8s node run container members?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Can we control the cluster node run a mount of container?
Example:A node can run max container 5,if we rc has 6,at this node we just can start 5 container.

Answer (score 0):

The number of pods allowed per node can be customized via a kubelet flag. So if you really wanted to control it on a node-by-node basis, you could start each kubelet with a different flag value.

In practice, it is probably better to use [resource requests and limits](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/compute-resources.html#resource-requests-and-limits-of-pod-and-container) to help the scheduler place an appropriate number of pods on each machine.

Answer (score 0):

In each node:

```
vi /etc/kubernetes/kubelet
update KUBELET_ARGS="" to KUBELET_ARGS="--max-pods=10
```

"

restart your kubeclt

Comment: Is this true even on CoreOS?  I thought it was kubelet.env file like Tony mentions here https://github.com/tonyzou/flexvolumes